# Disable the empty option in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I use `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple` in a `ModelForm` subclass to change the field display to checkboxes. The choices do become checkboxes but Django adds a first "empty" option with `---------` as the content.

This behavior is OK when displaying the field using the `Select` widget, because it force the user to explicitly choose an option. However when using checkboxes it becomes useless and rather confusing. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Err my bad, I should have looked carefully at the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). Anyway here is the solution:

> By default the  widget used by ModelChoiceField will have a an empty choice at the top of the list. You can change the text of this label (which is "---------" by default) with the empty_label attribute, or you can disable the empty label entirely by setting empty_label to None